# Editing large question crashes SE app for iOS

Tags: bug, edits, ios-app

Attempting to edit [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79743/45941) causes the iOS mobile app (1.4.5) to crash. I'm using an iPhone 6 with iOS 9.3.1.

Comment: Retagging as [tag:ios-app] since there's no issue on Android app.

Comment: @bacon Thanks, tagging on mobile is hard

Comment: I have this problem when my phone's storage was full. It might be because of that. I'm also using iPhone 6 with iOS 9.3.1.

Comment: @luweiqi I've used 13 gb, and have 36 gb remaining on my phone. I doubt that is the reason.

Comment: @Mego Yup, I can't even open the question as it crashed. Now, I've more than 1 GB left.

Comment: @BrianNickel Thanks! I seemed to have missed that question when I was searching before posting.